# Can you tell is the next sentence right?

Tags: sentence, locative-inversion

"Along one wall stood a low chest so richly brown as to appear black". Is this sentence right? As I know a subject is always followed by a predicate but in this sentence, the predicate is followed by the subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Language technique of preposition starting a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378701/language-technique-of-preposition-starting-a-sentence)

Comment: Where is the verb and where is the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence structure is called a [*locative inversion*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#Locative_inversion), where a prepositional phrase of location shifts to the beginning of the sentence and the subject and verb switch places. This creates a focus on the subject, which, as in this case, can be more easily and extensively modified.

> Near the front door stood an old oak hatrack, now laden with winter coats, which Marjorie had inherited from her grandmother.

A stylistic alternative is to insert a dummy subject *there* after the prepositional phrase:

> Near the front door there stood an old oak hatrack, now laden with winter coats, which Majorie had inherited from her grandmother.

This restores at least nominally the usual subject-verb order.